# A delegate crash when in another class-not main view

Tags: objective-c, crash

I have a delegate that used to work great.
but now i moved the delegate listener to some other class and i get crash.

Let say i have a main view, called `viewA` . and i have some initialiser class called `initialiser` .

In viewA which is the main view i do

```
Initializer *initi=[[Initializer alloc]init];
[initi fetchProgramData];
```

when fetchProgramData on the  Initializer is do :

```
//get categories and types
bsManager=[[BusinessManager alloc]init];
[bsManager setDelegate:self];
[bsManager getAllCategories];
```

and in this class i write the delegate method also ,to listen .

When i post the delegate , i get crash with no explanation .

If i set that listener in the main `viewA`, it works, but if its in another class, like `initialiser`, its crashes.
why?

Comment: How is the reference to your delegate class? Maybe it gets released, so only a weak reference?

Comment: @property(nonatomic,assign) id <businessDelegate>delegate;

Comment: What retains the delegate that you assign (`initialiser`)? What retains the object that retains it (`viewA`?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well had to put a property for that delegate to not lose him :

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)  Initializer *initi;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add exception breakpoint:

In exceptions menu select add Exception breakpoint:

[image: Select menu exceptions]
You will see here is a breakpoint:

[image]
And run you project, when you application crash. You can see detailed information about the crash.

Write what will be there, I can understand the problem.

Comment: i did that. its still not showing the error , but i can see on the left something about [PFTask thenCallbackOnMainThreadAsync]